# How to test the YouTube video Player using Protractor

Tags: protractor, youtube-javascript-api

I have a Youtube Video player on one of my angular pages. I also have a play button I created that programmatically tells the YouTube Javascript API to start playing the video.  Is there a way to get Protractor to test if the video is actually playing?  Since my Angular code already initialized the YouTube player, I am finding no ways in Google Search on how to query the player.  I investigated browser.executeScript but could find nothing that seemed to work...

**The Problem In more detail:**

If I could access the YouTube players' getCurrentTime(), or player.getPlayerState() functions, this problem would be a no-brainer, since my protractor test could just analyze the value of player.getPlayerState() 
but my research tells me that this is not possible inside of Protractor - since it is just a test runner and did not initialize the player itself (and thus has no reference to it)

I, therefore, have no way for protractor to make assertions on the position of the play head.

Based on my understanding of Javascript and protractor, I don't think it is possible to retrieve a reference to an already initialized YouTube Player in Protractor.  Do you know of ways to do this?

**Possible Alternative Approaches**

Here are some other ways I think we could test these features

1. Modify my player code to constantly write the current time to a hidden DOM element, and have my protractor tests query this DOM element using getText() 
   This, however, would probably slow down our app
2. Somehow subscribe to window messages events which Youtube may be broadcasting. During my research, I saw mention of messages being passed to the window object, is there someway we can read these messages using protractors browser.executeScript?  Do you know what messages may be broadcast by the YouTube Player?